# How to get count using group by with some category in sql server?

Tags: sql-server

Hi i am create one query for the who user follow intereset with the category i want to get count each period of time.
but i don't get correct result with my query. i don't where is my problem in the query. any one have the idea how can fix it.

This is my query =>

```
SELECT Name,count(SIF.InsertDateTime) as Count
 FROM dbo.InteresetInFollowers SIF
  INNER JOIN dbo.Users u on u.userid = sif.userid
  INNER JOIN dbo.SubCategoryIn ss on ss.SubCategoryInId = SIF.SubCategoryInId
  INNER JOIN dbo.CategoryIn s on s.CategoryInId = ss.CategoryInId
  WHERE SIF.IsFollowed = 1 
 GROUP BY Name,SIF.InsertDateTime

My current o/p =>
Name    |  Count
Cricket            5000
reading            1000

My expacted o/p =>
Name    |  Count
Cricket            2
reading            3

Here In my data base like this data is store =>

CategoryIn =>
 CategoryInId | Name
 1              Cricket
 2              reading



 SubCategoryIn =>
 SubCategoryInId |   CategoryInId      | Name
  1                    1                  balling
  2                    1                  batsman
  3                    2                  baybal
  4                    2                  story

 InteresetInFollowers=>
  InteresetInId | UserId | SubCategoryInId | IsFollow | InsertDateTime
  1                10        1                 1        2017-07-19 14:23:30.703
  2                20        2                 1       2017-07-19 14:23:30.703
  3                30        3                 1       2017-07-19 14:23:30.703 
  4                40        4                 1       2017-07-19 14:23:30.703
  5                50        3                 1       2017-07-19 14:23:30.703
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed.

```
SELECT name
,count(*) AS Count
FROM dbo.InteresetInFollowers SIF
INNER JOIN dbo.Users u ON u.userid = sif.userid
INNER JOIN dbo.SubCategoryIn ss ON ss.SubCategoryInId = SIF.SubCategoryInId
INNER JOIN dbo.CategoryIn s ON s.CategoryInId = ss.CategoryInId
WHERE SIF.IsFollowed = 1 AND CAST(InsertDateTime AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: i need to get just today counts? using date condition so how can do that?